# Android emulator open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, file, android-emulator, storage, android-permissions

I need help with permission to save file in Android emulator ... I've had added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

My code for save file:

```
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
   }

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();


        File myDir = new File(root + "/Img");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        long n = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String fname = "IMG_" + n + ".jpeg";
        file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(file);// here fire exception
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out2); 
            out2.flush();
            out2.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.denis.calculator">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".InfoActivity"></activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

Any ideas pls?

Comment: what exception you have exactly?

Comment: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: remove this lines `if (file.exists())
            file.delete();`

Comment: still not works :/

Comment: have you tried this on the real device? is this problem happen only on emulator?

Comment: Yes, on nexus ... and same issues

Comment: I`m debug the code and looks like Img folder is not created

Comment: @temnoi do you have idea why? :/

Comment: it may be permissions issue if you run this code on Marshmellow and above. just for test you can go to Settings-Apps select your app and allow access to external storage. if thats is the case then you should add permission checks

Comment: @temnoi I've added manifest to question, can you check this pls? When I allow permission in settings, application is shut down during saving.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the below lines

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

File myDir = new File(root + "/Img");
```

With

```
File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Img");
```

Also remove the below lines from your code

```
if (file.exists())
    file.delete();
```

Because the way you defining the file name will never gonna have the same file name. So validating the existence of file is irrelevant here.

You also have to ask writing permission with the user if your app is going to be used for Android 6.0 or above. Refer the link given below for details:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

You can use the solution defined in the library I've recently created this repository including a demo for Permission.

https://github.com/eeshan-jamal/DroidLibX

I will later make it available through Maven but for now you have to import the droidlibx library module in your project.

Comment: still not :/
on this line jump to catch
FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(file);

Comment: Yes I have .. on nexus :/

Comment: Can you please use file explorer app on your phone and check whether this Img directory created inside root directory or not?

Comment: It looks like not

Comment: Ahhh...It seems like you have writing permission issue. Are you using Android 6.0 or above OS in your device? If yes then you must have to implement the permission requestor either at launch/Use time because prior to 6.0 defining the permission in manifest is fine but from 6.0 you must have to get approval of using specific feature from user before use.

Comment: My api is target to 24 .. and on device using Nougat. I'm edited my question, and I've added manifest ... can you check it pls ?

Comment: You have to add the permission requestor model in your app by refering the link in my answer. Only defining it on Manifest is not gonna work for the Android OS releases Marshmallow, Nougat and future one's. The current solution will work only till lollipop OS. You can test in on emulator by creating a emulator targeting Lollipop OS.

Comment: @EJJ ok it works when I manually allow permission to storage ... can you show me some tutorial how it can be allowed in code for nougat?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is downgrade from Nougat to KitKat! thanks for advices

Comment: And Yeah!! This solution not gonna work further and might have ambiguous behaviour of your app on new OS.